# Como ordenar lista por ordem alfabetica no laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

Tenho uma `query` que me lista vários utilizadores eu quero ordenar esses utilizadores por ordem alfabética como posso fazer ?

**php**

```
private function getChilds(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {

    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent'] == $parentId) {
            $children = $this->getChilds($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                foreach ($children as $child){
                    $branch[] = $child;
                }
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

public function lista_jogadores (){

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $players = DB::table('players')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('agent', '=', $user_id)->get();

    $childs = DB::table('agents')->select('id', 'username', 'parent')->orderBy('username', 'ASC')->get();
    $childs_arr = array();
    foreach ($childs as $child){
        $child_arr = array(
            'id' => $child->id,
            'username' => $child->username,
            'parent' => $child->parent
        );
        $childs_arr[] = $child_arr;
    }
    $parents = $this->getChilds($childs_arr, $user_id);

    return view('admin.templates.jogadores', ['players' => $players])->with('parents',$parents);

}
```

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja fazer? Ordernar o que? Tipo se tem exemplo da tabela e como deveria vir os dados? Porque tem um evento de getChilds?

Answer (score 1):

```
$childs = DB::table('agents')
       ->select('id', 'username', 'parent')
       ->where('id', '>=', $user_id)
       ->orderBy('CAMPO', 'asc')
       ->get();
```

Comment: Coloquei assim mas não esta a ordenar não faz efeito

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset), utilize o método `orderBy`.

```
$childs = DB::table('agents')
->select('id', 'username', 'parent')
->where('id', '>=', $user_id)
->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
->get();
```

Comment: Eu tenho um utilizador chamado admin ordenei assim aparecem em ultimo nao deveria de aparecer em primeiro sendo por ordem alfabética o A e primeiro que a letra T por exemplo e isso que nao percebo

Comment: Você está ordenando pelo `username` mesmo? Tente trocar a ordem por decrescente e veja como se comporta: `->orderBy('username', 'DESC')`

Comment: Já tentei não muda nada tem mais um codigo alem desse que pode ser isso vou por o codigo

Comment: ja coloquei o codigo todo tando como desc ou asc nao muda nada

Comment: Qual o resultado de `var_dump( $childs );` ?

Comment: o resultado e este podes ver aqui https://pastebin.com/UdLFUbFF

Comment: Beleza. E qual o resultado de `var_dump($parents)`?

Comment: desculpe a demora mas tive ocupado esta aqui o https://pastebin.com/0rsdYJHf

Comment: Seu `array` não está retornando em ordem alfabética. Tente reordená-lo antes de passá-lo para a `view`.

Comment: Como posso ordernalo  em ordem alfabética antes de passar para a view e isso que nao sei